# Crawler para fazer paginação

Tags: java

Preciso de um crawler que faça paginação em um site.

Estou lendo o código fonte e gerando um txt dessa maneira

```
public class CodFonte {

public static void crawler(String str) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(str);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000);
    connection.connect();

    // read the output from the server
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String linha = "";

    String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\"; 
    String fileName = "Fonte Code.txt"; // Nome do arquivo

    FileWriter file = new FileWriter(path + fileName);
    PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(file);
    gravarArq.println("SITE -------- " + url);

    while ((linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        gravarArq.println(linha);
    }
     file.close();
    reader.close();
}

}
```

Mas preciso ir para próxima pagina, a url é amigável não muda de acordo com a requisição do form que é via POST.

Comment: Como é a estrutura da URL (paginação)? É um número?

Comment: é numero o input esta dentro de uma tabela ----   <input type="text" maxlength="4" maxsize="4" value="3" name="pag"></input>

Comment: E você já consegue ler este input pelo seu `java` acima?

Comment: Sim eu consigo chegar ate ele usando  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Comment: Bem, certa vez eu criei um crawler como este em PHP. A ideia era a mesma. A diferença é que eu colocava um link já com a próxma página no final da página, assim, eu clicava e ai a pagina atual era a próxima página. Você terá que usar um método de `sleep` (para aguardar entre uma página e outra) e usar um `loop` para seguir para a próxima página, além de uma condição de stop (ex.: `maxPaginasToCraw`). Antes, terá que ver quantas páginas existe, acessando todas elas e verificando  header do http (código 200) para salvar numa variável o total de páginas para usar no loop.

Comment: Essa parte de pegar o total de paginas eu consegui, tem uma div em que a pagina mesmo ja fala o total, entao eu soh faço umas condições e recupero o total, agora como submeter o post com os parametros?

Comment: Seu problema é só ir para a próxima página então? Você já consegue obter o código da página atual?

Comment: Sim, ja consigo ate gerar um txt da pagina atual, eh isso mesmo soh preciso saber  como submeter o formulario via post com esse crawler assim que eu tiver a proxima pagina eu consigo fazer o scan dela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo uma requisição post e obtendo o retorno, ajuda?

**`HttpURLConnectionExample.java`**

```
package com.meupacote.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 1 - Enviar request via POST");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://www.url.com/";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "param1=valor1&param2=valor2";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\Enviando 'POST' request para a URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Parâmetros parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Então, mas a url é amigavel, não muda, entao para que eu consiga ir para proxima pagina eu preciso mandar a requisição via post e assim recuperar a nova pagina

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Talvez eu não tenha entendido errado

Comment: Boa resposta! Mas, há algum motivo especial para usar `StringBuffer` ao invés de `StringBuilder`? Acho também que daria para usar a sintaxe *try-with-resources* para simplificar o código e deixá-lo mais robusto.

Comment: tranquilo, entao esse codigo eu creio que ja vai ajudar muito, como vc pegou os parametros que devem ser passados na requisição. Porque acho que estou passando os parametros errados

Comment: Acha então que os parâmetros estão errado, por isso o retorno não te ajuda?

Comment: porque, quando eu executo meu codigo ele retorna sempre a mesma pagina, fiz um laço para chamar a requisicao post com o total de paginas, o site que preciso fazer o crawler eh esse http://www.apinfo.com/apinfo/inc/list4.cfm. Preciso armazenar as vagas nesse site, mas nao consigo passar da primeira pagina

Comment: Entendi! Então, a URL para post é http://www.apinfo.com/apinfo/inc/list4.cfm e os parâmetros são `<input type="hidden" name="estado" value="99">
<input type="hidden" name="tv" value="351">
<input type="hidden" name="ddmmaa1" value="27/06/15">
<input type="hidden" name="ddmmaa2" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="onde" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="andor" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="keyw" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="pag" value="4">`

Comment: Basta setar em `String urlParameters = "param1=valor1&param2=valor2";` os parâmetros e ver o que retorna...o que retornará provavelmente será o HTML todo da página, prontos pra parsear usando parte do código do seu seu `crawler`

Comment: agora ficou claro, vou implementar aqui, vlw cara

Comment: Imagina! Acho que também vou fazer um da Apinfo em C#! Abraço

Comment: Cara testei aqui e funcionou certinho, eu estava fazendo uma coisa muito complicada utilizando Jsoup, do jeito que vc fez foi simples e direto vlw

Comment: Opa! Haha perfeito! Que ótimo!

Comment: cara sera que pode me dar uma ajuda em outro crawler ? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72459/crawler-para-fazer-login-no-site-da-nota-fiscal-paulista