# Crawler para fazer login no site da nota fiscal paulista

Tags: java

O que eu tenho até agora é isso:

```java
package br.com.crawler;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Crawler {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Crawler http = new Crawler();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 1 - Enviar request via POST");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://www.nfp.fazenda.sp.gov.br/login.aspx";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

             String urlParameters = "__EVENTVALIDATION=&"
            + "__EVENTARGUMENT=&"
            + "__VIEWSTATE=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&"
            + "ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo=rdBtnNaoContribuinte&"
            + "ConteudoPagina$Login1$UserName="+user+"&"
            + "ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$Password="+password;

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Enviando 'POST' request para a URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Parâmetros parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

A minha dúvida é que não sei quais parâmetros passar.

Comment: No caso os parâmetros que você não sabe quais seriam seria no `String urlParameters = "param1=valor1&param2=valor2";`?

Comment: issso, coloquei esse como exemplo apenas, mas deve ter algo como login e password  e mais alguns outros

Comment: to passando esses parametros --- `ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo=rdBtnContribuinte&ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo=rdBtnNaoContribuinte$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo=rdBtnContabilista$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo=rdBtnFazendario$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo=rdBtnProcon$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo=rdBtnAdvogadoRepresentante$ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$UserName=valor2$ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$Password=valor2`

Comment: mas parece que por ser radio button precisa mandar qual deles foi checked, eh nisso que estou travando

Comment: Poderia editar a questão para colocar estes detalhes? Fica mais fácil para entender do que ver nos comentários.

Comment: Editei, esse user e passward que estou passando eu vou receber do usuario.

Comment: Me parece que estão faltando vários `&` nos seus parâmetros.

Comment: Arrumei oq vc falou, executei mas ainda nao aceitou os parametros

Comment: Faltou um `&` depois do `user`.

Comment: Uma vez que o nome `ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo` dá a entender que isso é um radio button, acho que você só deveria colocar um deles, e não todos.

Comment: entao, essa questao do radio button que nao to sabendo passar, eu pesquisei umas coisas parece que tem que passar qual deles foi checked mas tentei de algumas maneiras e nao funcionou, talvez se eu passar apenas um deles funcione, vou testar vlw

Comment: adicionei uns inputs que estavam como hidden nos parametros, mas nao funcionou ele me mandar para uma tela dizendo que ocorreu uma falha na requisição

Comment: Se você acrescentar um `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` alguma coisa muda?

Comment: acrescentei, mas nao mudou nada me mandou para essa pag https://www.nfp.fazenda.sp.gov.br/Erro.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Crawler {

    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";

    private final String user;
    private final String password;
    private final TipoLogin tipo;

    public static enum TipoLogin {
        CONTRIBUINTE_ICMS("rdBtnContribuinte"),
        CONSUMIDOR("rdBtnNaoContribuinte"),
        CONTABILISTA("rdBtnContabilista"),
        FAZENDARIO("rdBtnFazendario"),
        PROCON("rdBtnProcon"),
        REPRESENTANTE_CONTRIBUINTE("rdBtnAdvogadoRepresentante");

        private final String radio;

        private TipoLogin(String radio) {
            this.radio = radio;
        }

        public String getRadio() {
            return radio;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Crawler http = new Crawler("12345678901", "$enh4", TipoLogin.CONTRIBUINTE_ICMS);
        http.sendPost();
    }

    public Crawler(String user, String password, TipoLogin tipo) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws IOException {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://www.nfp.fazenda.sp.gov.br/login.aspx");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }

        HttpsURLConnection get = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        get.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        get.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        get.getResponseCode();
        String page = download(get.getInputStream());

        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try {
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "__EVENTTARGET=" + buscarCampo(page, "__EVENTTARGET")
                + "&__EVENTARGUMENT=" + buscarCampo(page, "__EVENTARGUMENT")
                + "&__VIEWSTATE=" + buscarCampo(page, "__VIEWSTATE")
                + "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + buscarCampo(page, "__EVENTVALIDATION")
                + "&ctl00$ddlTipoUsuario=#rdBtnNaoContribuinte"
                + "&ctl00$UserNameAcessivel="
                + "&ctl00$PasswordAcessivel="
                + "&ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo=" + tipo.getRadio()
                + "&ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$UserName=" + escapeURI(user)
                + "&ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$Password=" + escapeURI(password);

        System.out.println("Parâmetros parameters : " + urlParameters);

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
        }

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Enviando 'POST' request para a URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

        String response = download(con.getInputStream());

        //print result
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    private static String download(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(1024);
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }

    private static String buscarCampo(String html, String campo) {
        String input = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + campo + "\" id=\"" + campo + "\" value=\"";
        int a = html.indexOf(input);
        if (a == -1) return "";
        int b = html.indexOf('\"', a + input.length());
        return html.substring(a + input.length(), b);
    }

    private static final String[] HEX = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};

    private static String escapeURI(byte c) {
        boolean ok = (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                || c == '-' || c == '.' || c == '_' || c == '~'
                || c == '$' || c == '#';
        return ok ? String.valueOf((char) c) : "%" + HEX[c >>> 4] + HEX[c & 0xF];
    }

    public static String escapeURI(String in) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(in.length() * 2);
        try {
            byte[] bytes = in.getBytes("UTF-8");
            IntStream.range(0, bytes.length).mapToObj(i -> escapeURI(bytes[i])).forEach(sb::append);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Estes campos `__EVENTTARGET`, `__EVENTARGUMENT`, `__VIEWSTATE` e `__EVENTVALIDATION` são problemáticos. Possivelmente estes campos podem ter valores aleatórios definidos pelo servidor que ele espera ler de volta. Por causa disso, primeiro eu faço um GET na página para pegar o valor destes campos e em seguida faço o POST com o valor de todos os campos.

Note os campos `ctl00$ddlTipoUsuario`, `ctl00$UserNameAcessivel` e `ctl00$PasswordAcessivel`. Estes campos estão na parte superior do formulário e são enviados junto com a requisição, mesmo se não forem necessários.

No final, os campos do formulário que te interessam (cujos valores são passados na chamada ao construtor dentro do `main(String[])`) são estes:

- O `ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$rblTipo` que corresponde aos radios buttons, e pode ser `rdBtnContribuinte`, `rdBtnNaoContribuinte`, `rdBtnContabilista`, `rdBtnFazendario`, `rdBtnProcon` ou `rdBtnAdvogadoRepresentante`.
- O `ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$UserName` que é o nome do usuário.
- O `ctl00$ConteudoPagina$Login1$Password` que é a senha.

Observe que eu estou usando um *encoding* do usuário e da senha para "escapar" caracteres especiais.

Provavelmente há mais coisas que deixei para trás. Me avise nos comentários se conseguir ou não.

Comment: @roque https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-

Comment: passei os parametro de usuario e senha, mas redirecionou para a pagina de erro também

Comment: Tenta usar algum plugin do navegador como o webdeveloper para ver exatamente o que o navegador envia no seu caso (tanto no corpo da requisição como nos cabeçalhos). Eu pessoalmente não tenho como testar porque não possuo login e senha.

Comment: tranquilo, vou tentar descobrir como ele esta passando essa requisição, a parte java ja esta pronto eh soh descobrir os parametros mesmo mas ja ajudou muito vlw cara

Comment: cara consegui passar os parametros, mas ta pedindo captcha, tem uma maneira de passar na requisição para desabilitar o captcha?

Comment: @roque Acho que não, porque se houvesse uma forma de desabilitar o captcha, então para que o captcha serviria afinal? O melhor a fazer é tentar usar algum quebrador de captcha.

Comment: consegui os parametros sem habilitar o captcha, mas ainda tenho um problema que é o seguinte, quando eu jogo no browser a url e os parametros ele faz login certinho, mas quando eu executo meu codigo ele continua na pagina de login - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73293/enviar-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-via-get